# Separating data from a single line in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a way to separate a single line of text into different cells based on a character?

IE: This string needs to be separated - The first name is kar#, followed by a number. Is it possible to separate kar# and the number that follows, and for the remaining data. Like a find function for # and it returns data 1 from find and so on? Thanks! <3

```
kar# 1,910.0k|joule# 1,731.0k|miss# 1,672.1k|talli# 1,625.1k|butter# 1,591.8k| kulka# 1,278.3k|risin# 1,257.4k|robste# 1,171.4k|dub# 1,157.5k|ulfval# 1,071.5k| ayma# 1,007.6k|kakaro# 1,007.2k|smile# 993.0k|imba# 980.9k|mattyliciou# 965.3k| udi# 917.7k|mad# 910.4k|redbir# 830.2k|epi# 821.2k|sof# 804.1k| keato# 730.8k|kevy# 728.3k|mik# 690.3k|juru# 628.2k|nutz# 577.1k|
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(A1; "|")); " "))
```

[image]